# Google Analytics - Report not being populated

Tags: google-analytics

My mobile app `Screen Views` are being tracked in analytics, but when I try to create a report from the data, I've got nothing. I've logged in/out, waited about 30 minutes, and tried a few different report options. I read the docs and set the report up accordingly. Am I missing something?

[Screen Views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dslwW.png)

[Report Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YfhD.png)

[Report Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub5Fk.png)

Comment: They appeared, it just took over an hour. Marking as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They all ended up appearing, it just took about 90 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  In two days, you will be able to accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.  That will indicate that the problem has been solved.